# Google Sheets: How to compare 2 tables and return all rows with matching lines

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get a table working to compare two assets and get a summary of all matches.

I have two tables (`#t1#` and `#t2#`) with two necessary columns, (name and availability) in column `B` and `J`.
Now I want to compare those two tables with each other and print all rows to `#t3#` where both entries under `name` have the similarity of `availability` being `no`.

e.g.
#t1#

| name | availability |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | yes |
| Peach | no |
| Grape | no |

#t2#

| name | availability |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | no |
| Peach | no |
| Grape | yes |

#t3#

| name | availability |
| --- | --- |
| Peach | no |

Anyone willing to help out?

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
=index(let(a,filter(A2:A&"|"&B2:B,B2:B="no"),b,filter(D2:D&"|"&E2:E,E2:E="no"),split(ifna(filter(a,xmatch(a,b))),"|")))
```

[image]